# What does it mean to expand a Hamiltonian using perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, approximations

On [UC Davis chemwiki website](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Magnetic_Resonance_Spectroscopies/Nuclear_Magnetic_Resonance/NMR%3A_Theory/NMR_Interactions/Quadrupolar_Coupling#Expansion_of_the_Hamiltonian), the Hamiltonian for quadrupolar coupling in NMR is analyzed. (The details of this aren't important.)

It is said in the analysis that:

> *The expansion of the Hamiltonian is done using [perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29).*

It then proceeds to "expand the Hamiltonian" according to first and second order terms.

I'm an undergraduate reading up on quantum physics for a summer research position, and I've spent the last day or so immersing myself in perturbation theory. It's my understanding that the basic premise of the theory is that there are two (and only two) parts to the Hamiltonian: $H^0$, the unperturbed Hamiltonian, and $H^1$, the perturbing one. What does it mean to expand the Hamiltonian itself?

---

EDIT: It appears the premise of this question is mistaken. As far as I can tell, perturbation theory itself **doesn't** result in first- and second-order Hamiltonians. Instead, NMR researchers have just happened to call a pair of Hamiltonians "first-order" and "second-order". Since both of these are perturbing Hamiltonians, I got confused at the overlap in terminology.

Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Comment: This is explained in any reasonable book on QM. See, for instance, Griffiths' book, ch. 6.

Comment: Hmmm. That reference is indeed quite confusing, and it's not very clear what they are doing. Do you have additional references that parallel this treatment? It doesn't look like they are doing a perturbation expansion, it looks to me (right off the bat) like a full expansion of the change from the Principal Axis System into the lab frame.

Comment: @Danu I just read over Griffith's chapter 6. It's a great reference but nowhere does it answer this question.

Comment: @NcAdams My sincere apologies: I was under the impression that it was the 'standard expansion' you were asking after, which is explained there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I agree, the paper doesn't really explain itself. It may just be changing coordinates; however, I've seen a lot of references to "first-order" and "second-order" terms in the quadrupolar Hamiltonian. Section 2.1 of [this paper](http://www.pascal-man.com/EACself.pdf) has a better explanation

Comment: Well, is there some particular part of the Man paper that you're struggling with?

Comment: I guess not. I'm going to assume my question's premise is false, and that perturbation theory doesn't generate "first-order" and "second-order" Hamiltonians. (I'll edit to reflect that.) Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: I _think_ what they mean is that the perturbed Hamiltonian is actually itself very complicated, and so they will "perturb the perturbed Hamiltonian." This is a little tricky and not a standard intro QM thing. In other words, when they talk about "perturbing the hamiltonian," they do not mean that they are going to compute perturbations to the energy spectrum using QM perturbation theory [though they will ultimately do this later on]. What they mean is that the hamiltonian $H_Q$ that represents the "quadrupolar correction" is very complicated and depends on the exact shape of the nucleus,...

Comment: ...so they will do a multipole expansion on $H_Q$ itself. So there are two approximations going on: (1) First we are approximating the energy spectrum using QM perturbation theory with a perturbed hamiltonian $H_1=H_Q+...$ (where ... refers to other corrections that might be present besides the quadrupolar one), and (2) $H_Q$ itself will be approximated with a different hamiltonian that is easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's closer to what I originally thought. Do you know a source/keyword that could help me learn more?